# Creating a view event in db **'RentalDate' in field list is ambiguous**

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

*'RentalDate' in field list is ambiguous*

```
drop view if exists event;
create view event as
select concat(customer.firstname, " ", customer.surname) as title, 
Concat(DATE_FORMAT(RentalDate,'%Y-%m-%d'), "T", StartTime) as start, 
concat("Equipmentitem: " ,equipmentitem.id) as equipment,rental.id as id
from customer, equipmentitem, rental
where customer.ID = rental.CustomerID and equipmentitem.id=rental.EquipmentID;
```

This is the table in the db

```
Create Table Rental
(
    RentalID    integer,
    RentalDate  Datetime,
    ReturnDate  Datetime,
    RentalInvoice Integer,
    Primary Key(RentalID),
    Foreign Key(CustomerID) references Customer(CustomerID),
    Foreign Key(DeliveryID) references Delivery(DeliveryID),

);

Insert into Rental(RentalID, RentalDate, ReturnDate,  RentalInvoice,) values(1,'2018-3-8','2019-3-8','3');
Insert into Rental(RentalID, RentalDate, ReturnDate,  RentalInvoice,) values(2,'2017-3-8','2018-3-8','4');
Insert into Rental(RentalID, RentalDate, ReturnDate,  RentalInvoice,) values(3,'2018-1-6','2019-2-6','5');
Insert into Rental(RentalID, RentalDate, ReturnDate,  RentalInvoice,) values(4,'2018-4-10','2018-3-12','6');
Insert into Rental(RentalID, RentalDate, ReturnDate,  RentalInvoice,) values(5,'2018-2-7','2019-3-11','8');
Insert into Rental(RentalID, RentalDate, ReturnDate,  RentalInvoice,) values(6,'2018-3-8','2019-3-9','7');
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that 'RentalDate' is common to different tables

try

```
Concat(DATE_FORMAT(<nameOfTable>.RentalDate,'%Y-%m-%d'), "T", <nameOfTable>.StartTime) as start
```